How to async-initialize DI element based on JS in Blazor Server?
In Blazor WebAsm it is quite easy -- JS is not scoped, so all it takes is getting given element from DI, calling InitializeAsync on it, and that's it.
In Blazor Server I cannot find out good solution. On one hand I can synchronously call async-init when creating element for DI, like for example:
        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IFeedbackControl),
            sp =>
            {
                var signalr_obs = new SignalrControl(
                    sp.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>(), 
                    Routes.SignalR);
                InitializeAsync(sp, signalr_obs).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                return signalr_obs;
            },
            lifetime));
    }


In WebAsm it is not possible to call GetAwaiter().GetResult(), in Blazor Server it is, but it is not good enough -- after first call to JS the program freezes (when debugging it is seen as never returning, however the call has effect -- I checked calling console.log).
For now the other approach I can see would be removing this async-init from DI (because it does not work), and each time I acquire element from DI I would initialize it. It translates to scenarios like having 1000 pages, I would have to 1000 times initialize it. It does not seem right.
Is there some good way to do it? On par with WebAsm -- initialize it once and forget about it.
